# Real endomorphism algebra of abelian surface is never $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, abelian-varieties, division-algebras

I'm reading about the Sato Tate conjecture for genus 2, and I came to the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.6478.pdf).  This breaks the conjecture into 6 different parts, based on the real endomorphism algebra of the surface, or the connected component of the Sato Tate group.  They point to the classification [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.6638.pdf), which claims in section 4.1 that "Albert’s classification of division algebras with involution (see [Mu70]), together with the work of Shimura [Sh63], show that the R-algebra $End_{\mathbb{R}}(A_K)$ is isomorphic to one of" $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C},M_2(\mathbb{R})$ or $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Conspicuously not on the list is $\mathbb{C}$.  Is there a good reason for $\mathbb{C}$ to be able to be the endomorphism algebra of an elliptic curve, yet not an abelian surface?  Why can an abelian surface have real multiplication but not complex multiplication?